# Apache Camel on Karaf with Spring DSL + OSGi

Tags: spring, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, spring-dm

I am new to OSGI world.

Versions:
Karaf: 4.1.0
Camel: 2.18.2
Spring: 4.3.5_RELEASE_1 (Apache Service Mix Bundles)

Ref: [Camel-UserForum-on same question](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-with-OSGI-in-Felix-with-Spring-DSL-tc5794738.html)

I spent lot of time (even days ) in searching/understanding camel-spring with osgi container. I didn't find a good article for begginer like me which works with some setup or github..etc.

We are having camel-spring application running well. Now we want to move to OSGI environment like Karaf .
We are doing some work on migration to OSGI, we are having severe issues we were able to solve couple of them ,but end up with having  below issues:

1. I dont know where to place camel-spring xml context and route  files (previuosly in classpath with NON-OSGi) .So its not loading context getting file not found .
2. if I put that as below , i know its may be a wrong way

   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
           new String[] {"file:app-camel-spring.xml" });
   Exception:
   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]
   Offending resource: URL [file:app-camel-spring.xml]

Even with Spring DM it doesn't work

Thanks,

**Update-1**
1. After forums asked me to look into GEMINI Blueprint(GB) I am now checking with GB. But Still I am getting same error with JAXB errors.

I am using now :
Felix:

```
  runtimelib group: 'org.apache.felix', name: 'org.apache.felix.gogo.command', version: '1+'
  runtimelib group: 'org.apache.felix', name: 'org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime', version: '1+'
  runtimelib group: 'org.apache.felix', name: 'org.apache.felix.gogo.shell', version: '1+'
  runtimelib group: 'org.apache.felix', name: 'org.apache.felix.bundlerepository', version: '2+'
  runtimelib group: 'org.apache.felix', name: 'org.apache.felix.fileinstall', version: '3+'
  runtimelib group: 'org.apache.felix', name: 'org.apache.felix.scr.annotations', version: '1.12.0'
```

Bundle List:

```
  lb
  START LEVEL 1
     ID|State      |Level|Name
      0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (5.6.2)|5.6.2
      1|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (2.0.8)|2.0.8
      2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix File Install (3.5.8)|3.5.8
      3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (1.0.2)|1.0.2
      4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (1.0.2)|1.0.2
      5|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (1.0.0)|1.0.0
      6|Active     |    1|file:/E:/Codes/GIT/Repos/Experiments/osgi/felix/bundle/org.apache.felix.scr.annotations-1.12.0.jar (0.0.0)|0.0.0
      7|Active     |    1|Apache MINA Core (2.0.14)|2.0.14
      8|Active     |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-context (4.3.1.RELEASE_1)|4.3.1.RELEASE_1
      9|Active     |    1|Logback Core Module (1.1.1)|1.1.1
     10|Active     |    1|slf4j-api (1.7.21)|1.7.21
     11|Active     |    1|camel-mina2 (2.18.0)|2.18.0
     12|Active     |    1|osgi_testing.test_cons (0.0.4.1488767989530)|0.0.4.1488767989530
     13|Active     |    1|Logback Classic Module (1.1.1)|1.1.1
     14|Active     |    1|Old JAXB Runtime (2.2.11)|2.2.11
     15|Active     |    1|Apache Log4j (1.2.17)|1.2.17
     16|Active     |    1|gemini-blueprint-core (2.0.9.BUILD-atlassian-m003)|2.0.9.BUILD-atlassian-m003
     17|Installed  |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-context-support (4.3.1.RELEASE_1)|4.3.1.RELEASE_1
     18|Active     |    1|camel-core (2.18.0)|2.18.0
     19|Active     |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: aopalliance (1.0.0.6)|1.0.0.6
     20|Active     |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-tx (4.3.1.RELEASE_1)|4.3.1.RELEASE_1
     21|Active     |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-core (4.3.1.RELEASE_1)|4.3.1.RELEASE_1
     22|Active     |    1|gemini-blueprint-extender (2.0.9.BUILD-atlassian-m003)|2.0.9.BUILD-atlassian-m003
     23|Active     |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-beans (4.3.1.RELEASE_1)|4.3.1.RELEASE_1
     24|Active     |    1|osgi_testing.test_impl2 (0.0.1.1488767989534)|0.0.1.1488767989534
     25|Active     |    1|camel-spring (2.18.0)|2.18.0
     26|Active     |    1|Apache Commons Logging (1.2.0)|1.2.0
     27|Active     |    1|test_api (0.0.2.1488767989527)|0.0.2.1488767989527
     28|Active     |    1|Apache Commons IO (2.5.0)|2.5.0
     29|Active     |    1|Old JAXB Core (2.2.11)|2.2.11
     30|Active     |    1|osgi_testing.test_impl3 (0.0.1.1488767989536)|0.0.1.1488767989536
     31|Active     |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-expression (4.3.1.RELEASE_1)|4.3.1.RELEASE_1
     32|Active     |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-aop (4.3.1.RELEASE_1)|4.3.1.RELEASE_1
     33|Active     |    1|gemini-blueprint-io (2.0.9.BUILD-atlassian-m003)|2.0.9.BUILD-atlassian-m003
     34|Active     |    1|osgi_testing.test_impl (0.0.1.1488767989532)|0.0.1.1488767989532
  g! start 17
  org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support [17](R 17.0): missing requirement 
  [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support [17](R 17.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache) 
  Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support [17](R 17.0)] osgi.wiring.package; 
  (osgi.wiring.package=com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache)]



   10:41:25.836 [fileinstall-load] ERROR com.tp.boot.ApplicationBootActivator - ERROR::
  org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]
  Offending resource: URL [file:app-camel-spring.xml]

          at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:301) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1408) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93) ~[na:na]
          at com.tp.boot.ApplicationBootActivator.start(ApplicationBootActivator.java:54) ~[na:na]
          at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697) ~[felix.jar:na]
          at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2238) ~[felix.jar:na]
          at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144) ~[felix.jar:na]
          at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998) ~[felix.jar:na]
          at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1253) ~[na:na]
          at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1225) ~[na:na]
          at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:512) ~[na:na]
          at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361) ~[na:na]
          at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:312) ~[na:na]
  10:41:25.870 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: osgi_testing.test_api
  10:41:25.903 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: org.apache.mina.core
  10:41:25.915 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: ch.qos.logback.core
  10:41:25.928 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: slf4j.api
  10:41:25.954 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-core
  10:41:25.990 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.core
  10:41:26.022 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.device.rba.Activator - Started [osgi_testing.test_impl3]
  10:41:26.035 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: osgi_testing.test_impl3
  10:41:26.096 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-impl
  10:41:26.123 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.Activator - start CONS
  10:41:26.131 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.Activator - Device Bundle Tracker - started
  10:41:26.139 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.DeviceHub -  Device [rbaonguard] ClassName [com.tp.device.rba.RBADeviceImpl] Added
  10:41:26.188 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.DeviceHub - Written to File [Config/devices]
  10:41:26.195 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.DeviceServiceTracker - Service Reference- Added  Device [rbaonguard] Device Class [com.tp.device.rba.RBADeviceImpl]
  10:41:26.204 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.DeviceHub -  Device [rbavoltagetep2] ClassName [com.tp.device.rba.RBADeviceImpl] Added
  10:41:26.218 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.DeviceHub - Written to File [Config/devices]
  10:41:26.225 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.DeviceServiceTracker - Service Reference- Added  Device [rbavoltagetep2] Device Class [com.tp.device.rba.RBADeviceImpl]
  10:41:26.240 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.DeviceHub -  Device [xpi] ClassName [com.tp.device.xpi.XPIDeviceImpl] Added
  10:41:26.266 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.DeviceHub - Written to File [Config/devices]
  10:41:26.271 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.DeviceServiceTracker - Service Reference- Added  Device [xpi] Device Class [com.tp.device.xpi.XPIDeviceImpl]
  10:41:26.278 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG com.tp.app.cons.Activator - Device Service Tracker - started
  10:41:26.283 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: osgi_testing.test_cons
  10:41:26.295 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-tx
  10:41:26.832 [EclipseGeminiBlueprintExtenderThread-1] INFO  o.e.g.b.c.s.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext - About to begin startRefresh for osgi_testing.test_api [27]
  10:41:26.985 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender
  10:41:27.000 [EclipseGeminiBlueprintExtenderThread-2] INFO  o.e.g.b.c.s.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext - About to begin startRefresh for osgi_testing.test_api [27]
  10:41:27.336 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aopalliance
  10:41:27.455 [fileinstall-load] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator - Bundle started: ch.qos.logback.classic
  10:41:27.559 [EclipseGeminiBlueprintExtenderThread-1] DEBUG o.a.c.s.h.CamelNamespaceHandler - Using org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean as CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser
  10:41:27.561 [EclipseGeminiBlueprintExtenderThread-2] DEBUG o.a.c.s.h.CamelNamespaceHandler - Using org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean as CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser
  10:41:27.762 [EclipseGeminiBlueprintExtenderThread-2] DEBUG o.e.g.b.c.s.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext - Pre refresh error for osgi_testing.test_api [27]
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to create the JAXB binder; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.apache.camel.model.config" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
   - with linked exception:
  [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.apache.camel.model.config" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]
          at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:380) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:61) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[na:na]
          at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:170) ~[na:na]
          at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:140) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[na:na]
          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612) ~[na:na]
          at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$800(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:63) ~[na:na]
          at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$3.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:249) ~[na:na]
          at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85) ~[na:na]
          at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.startRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:224) ~[na:na]
          at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.stageOne(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:224) ~[na:na]
          at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.refresh(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:177) ~[na:na]
          at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:159) ~[na:na]
          at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.activator.LifecycleManager$1.run(LifecycleManager.java:207) ~[na:na]
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
  Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.apache.camel.model.config" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
          at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
          at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
          at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
          at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
          at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.newJAXBContext(DefaultModelJAXBContextFactory.java:31) ~[na:na]
          at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.getJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:217) ~[na:na]
          at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:378) ~[na:na]
          ... 28 common frames omitted
  Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.apache.camel.model.config" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
          at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
          at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
          ... 35 common frames omitted
  10:41:27.770 [EclipseGeminiBlueprintExtenderThread-1] DEBUG o.e.g.b.c.s.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext - Pre refresh error for osgi_testing.test_api [27]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Apache Karaf 4.0.8 as 4.1.0 is buggy and not supported for that Camel release.

And the spring XML files should be placeholder in the folder as shown in that example, eg `META-INF/spring`.

But mind that Spring DM is deprecated and dead. So its highly recommended to use OSGi Blueprint instead.

And in the future Karaf will have some kind of spring XML to blueprint XML auto converter so it can run spring xml files as if they are blueprints. But for more details on that ask on the Karaf community.

Comment: ok thanks. I tried using karaf 4.0.8 now. I also came to know that GEMINI Blueprint is the way we can dela with spring in osgi environment. Do we have any camel example with CAMEL+SPRING+GEMINI BLUEPRINT+KARAF ? for time being i cannot move to blueprint Aries .

Comment: No there is no example of that. Apache Camel only support Apache Blueprint from Apache Felix

Comment: OK thanks alot for your time. We will start think of blueprint then.

Answer (score 1):

```
[caused by: Unable to resolve camel-spring-dm/2.18.2: missing requirement
[camel-spring-dm/2.18.2] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=spring-dm;
```

The error is pretty clear, the feature resolver can't find the spring-dm feature, you need to install it first

```
feature:install spring-dm
```

If i'm correct, karaf dropped the support to spring-dm, so the feature may not be available, you will need to install spring-dm manually. But like was already said, spring-dm is way deprecated and a very buggy way to use spring at an OSGi enviroment. You should move to aries blueprint, or if spring is really indispensable, you should use gemini-blueprint, it's a blueprint implementation compatible with Spring 4.2.x .

https://eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/
http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/migration/

Comment: I started experimenting with gemini blueprint with Spring and Camel, lets see.. But I am still getting jaxb issues with 
"org.apache.camel.mode.config"

Answer (score 0):

Finally moving out of Camel-Spring with OSGi. Its a a nightmare combination to try. Lots of issues with this combination.

Now Trying Camel+Blueprint+Karaf.

Thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 0):

With Karaf 4.2.3, Camel 2.22.3 and Spring 5.1 it works just like with old spring-dm and Spring 3.2.
It worked for me for an old integration crafted years ago for Spring 3.2 and Spring DM using:

- services/references, tested with referencing transaction manager
- compendium properties
- @Transactional annotation on bean's method which also correctly created transaction aspect

Above proves it is doable and should allow most of the old integrations to work almost out of the box.
There are possible benefits also over blueprint- like being able to use Spring Data (not tested yet) for example with mongo, which I am also looking at.

Obviously, you need to recompile your project with new dependencies to get your manifest right.

It works thanks to what Claus has mentioned- the Spring to Blueprint compatibility layer.
The feature providing this functionality is called "aries-blueprint-spring".
I am not using it yet in real life, but I am doing research on how to migrate our Spring integrations from Karaf 2 (Fuse 6.3) to Karaf 4 (Fuse 7.2).
I am not personally big fan of blueprint, as it has some annoying limitations especially if you have been using Spring for more than a decade like me.

The compatibility layer is not perfect yet as:

1. It has some non-critical bugs- like if you restart the bundle with camel route, it will fail to start with some "template" bean registration error, which I am sure will be addressed by the community at some point.
   This seems to be related to this issue done decade ago: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-1899 where Camel is adding some extra beans which was created to improve unit testing.
   You can workaround it until fixed by adding to your Spring Context:

   ```
   <bean id="template" class="java.lang.String"/>
   <bean id="fluentTemplate" class="java.lang.String"/>
   <bean id="consumerTemplate" class="java.lang.String"/>
   ```
2. I cannot get spring deployer to work- deploying raw Spring XMLs as bundles, like as we use for JDBC connection pool for bundles. But this is a niche approach- a nice to have.

Also, there are problems with ActiveMQ 5 client which currently works only with Spring 4, but there is a solution for that from Red Hat as they have their own version of ActiveMQ client, which seems to work with Spring 5.

With all the above, you should be sorted and happy to use Spring 5 with Camel in Karaf 4.2.3.

Update

Sadly community decided to kill camel spring support for karaf.
Camel 3 spring component does not work anymore and fails on class and resources loading.